# c# string.replace in foreach loop

Tags: c#, string, foreach

Somehow I can't seem to get string replacement within a foreach loop in C# to work. My code is as follows :

```
foreach (string s in names)
{
    s.Replace("pdf", "txt");
}
```

Am still quite new to LINQ so pardon me if this sounds amateurish ;)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You say you're after a LINQ solution... that's easy:

```
var replacedNames = names.Select(x => x.Replace("pdf", "txt"));
```

We don't know the type of `names`, but if you want to assign back to it you could potentially use `ToArray` or `ToList`:

```
// If names is a List<T>
names = names.Select(x => x.Replace("pdf", "txt")).ToList();
// If names is an array
names = names.Select(x => x.Replace("pdf", "txt")).ToArray();
```

You should be aware that the code that you've posted isn't using LINQ at all at the moment though...

Answer (score 26):

Strings in C# are immutable (does not change), so `s.Replace` will return a new string. Unfortunately this means you cannot use `foreach` to do the update. If names is an array this should work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    names[i] = names[i].Replace("pdf", "txt");
}
```

Comment: It will work for a `List<string>` too. Just replace _Length_ with _Count_

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned you'd need to use a `for` loop to do this in-place. However, if you don't need the operation to be done in-place (i.e. the results can be a different collection), then you could also do it as a linq query, e.g.

```
var results = from name in names select name.Replace("pdf", "txt");
```

One thing though - it looks like you are trying to change the extension of some file names. If that's what you are trying to do then I'd recommend [`Path.ChangeExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx) which is specifically designed for this purpose.

```
var results = from name in names select Path.ChangeExtension(name, "txt");
```

Comment: Using a query expression here seems overkill - if you're just doing a single Select, why not call it directly? +1 for Path.ChangeExtension though.

Comment: @Jon - I just think that query expressions look nicer and are a little easier to read. It all compiles down to the same code, and typing a few extra characters doesn't really bother me. If I was doing something that can't be expressed in a query such as using skip/take or converting to a list then I'd probably use the extension methods directly.

Comment: I guess it's just personal preference... I certainly love query expressions when they get more complicated, but if you're just doing a single filter or a single projection, they seem a less direct way of expressing that.

Comment: @Jon - Another reason for me is that often simple queries can turn into more complex ones, e.g. in the above code I might need to add `where Path.GetExtension(name) == ".pdf"` to make the code using the `Path` class match the intent of the original. Writing it as a query in the first place means it doesn't have to be changed too much if it gets more complex in the future. But to be honest I don't care that much either way, and it probably depends more on what mood I'm  in or how the other queries in the method are written as much as anything!

Answer (score 0):

s.Replace is a function so you would like s=s.Replace().. although it's better to use StringBuilder. (see upper answer)

Comment: Why would using a StringBuilder be better here? It's not like multiple replacements are being performed on the *same* string.

Answer (score -3):

Why use replace? It will make the application slow. Use regex instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx

Comment: Not according to this guys tests: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance.aspx